# Antiderivative of a function of the antiderivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

I've got $\frac{\partial y(x(t),t)}{\partial t} = c * (x(t) - y(x, t))$

Let's consider the general case where $\frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial t} = f(y(t))$

Given that the derivative depends on the original, how do I get the antiderivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation
$$
y_t - f(y) = 0
$$
contains both the function $y$ and its partial derivative regarding time $y_t$, such is called a partial differential equation (PDE) in this case a [first order non-linear PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_partial_differential_equation).

This is a vast field with a multitude of solution techniques.

Comment: Interesting, but I still don't know the solution, or any of the ways to get there. Can you please show me any of the solution techniques applicable for my situation?

Comment: What information does it lack?

Comment: Stuff like what kind of functions $y$ and $f$ are. Then you have the equivalent to the integration constant, which means the solution set contains more than one function unless you single it out via initial or boundary conditions.

Comment: $f(y) = c(x-y)$ as in the question, but what $y$ is is exactly what I'm trying to figure out. Let's say that $y=0$ at $t=0$. $c$ is constant. $x$ is a function of $t$ alone.

Comment: So $y = y(x,t)$, $x = x(t)$, $f(x,y,t) = c (x(t) - y(x,t))$? Or are $x$ and $t$ independent variables?

Comment: For my specific example, we don't need to consider $f$. See updated question. As for my generalized example: I think I should accept your answer.